# Cairo and high DPI drawing (drawing on retina surfaces, OS X)

Tags: macos, drawing, cairo

My application draws some images using cairo like this:

```
cairo_set_source_surface(cr, _page_down_icon, icon_x, y);
cairo_paint(cr);
```

where the page down icon is a png I loaded via `cairo_image_surface_create_from_png`.

This works fine on standard screens but produces a low quality image on retina displays. So I'm thinking of having a second image with double resolution (as it is usual for NSImage). However, if I just draw this image the result is twice as large as the standard image. So my question is: how would I draw the highres image with cairo on a retina display so that it looks crisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cairo_scale is your friend. With this method you can adjust the scaling of the axes of your surface. In order to get the result you want youd scale by 0.5 for your second image (not that you'll have to adjust the targetposition for the image as well!).

Comment: Does this mean I have to set a scale factor right before I draw the image and reset it afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so. You scale before calling set_source_surface. The scaling is applied to your cairo context, so you will have to reset it when your're done drawing or will remain active for all future operations on the context.